# How to cancel all other ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pjax

I have a SPA website.

When I send request A, I find I clicked wrong link. So I click and send request B before complete request A. So I want to abort request A and all other requests. I tried `XMLHttpRequest.abort();` but it is only abort request B.

Simple Source Code :

```
function link(){
const request=new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','//example.com/',true);
request.send();
request.onload=()=>{
console.log('Loaded');
}
}
```

Full Source Code :

```xml
link(to){
    const requeset=new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET','/api/window.location,true);
    request.send();
    request.onload=function(){
    console.log('hello!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep the reference to the specific request object and call abort on that. For any more detailed answer, you should post a [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the previous request something like...

```js
var lastRequest = null;

// Loop through all action buttons
document.querySelectorAll('button.action').forEach(button => {

    // Attach a click event listener
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

        // If there was a previous request, kill it.
    if (lastRequest) {
      lastRequest.abort();
      lastRequest = null;
    }

        // Now make the new request and store the reference.
    lastRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    lastRequest.open('GET', 'https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3');
    lastRequest.onload = () => {
      lastRequest = null; // We reset the last request reference on load.
    };
    lastRequest.send();
  });
})
```

```html
<button class="action">Action 1</button>
<button class="action">Action 2</button>
```

---

**UPDATE**

```js
function link(to) {

    // If there was a previous request, kill it.
    if (window._myLastLinkRequest) {
        window._myLastLinkRequest.abort();
        window._myLastLinkRequest = null;
    }


    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    request.open('GET','/api/' + window.location, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        console.log('hello!');
        window._myLastLinkRequest = null; // We reset the last request reference on load.
    };
    request.send();

    // Now store the reference to the new request.
    window._myLastLinkRequest = request;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I use it in function so variable can't save.

Comment: @NaweGa that shouldn't stop you from storing the last request in a variable, please post your full function code so we can help you better!

Comment: I edited my question and add full function.

Comment: @NaweGa please see my update

Answer (score 1):

You should save your last request in some way.

If you are handling your request "B", you can check if there is still an ongoing request by checking the readyState of your previous xhr. In my exmaple it's

```
$previousHxr
```

```
//function to handle the xhr
if($previousHxr.readyState !== 4){
    $previousHxr.cancel();
}
```